# Perl critic error on splitting string into array using regexp

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, split, perl-critic

```
sub func {
    my ($n) = @_;
    return unless ($n);
    my @array;
    push @array, $1 while $n =~ /
            ((?:
              [^(),]+ |
              ( \(
                (?: [^()]+ | (?2) )*
              \) )
            )+)
            (?: ,\s* | $)
            /xg;

    return \@array;
    }

    for my $item (@array) {
        if (index($item, '$n') != -1) {
           print "HELLO\n";
        }
}
```

I have above regex to split some string into array. It works fine.

Problem is :

Perl critic gives below errors. Please advise how do i fix this.

```
Capture variable used outside conditional at line 150, 
    near 'push @array, $1 while $n =~ /'.  (Severity: 3)
```

```
Use '{' and '}' to delimit multi-line regexps at line 150, 
    near 'push @input_expression, $1 while $n =~ /'.  (Severity: 1)
```

```
String *may* require interpolation at line 168, 
    near '$item, '$n''.  (Severity: 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl Critic doesn't give any errors. It gives policy violations.

To fix the first one, change the loop from modifier to normal while loop and name the variable:

```
    while ($n =~ /
        ...

    /xg) {
        my $match = $1;
        push @array, $match;
    }
```

To fix the second one, just change `/.../` to `m{...}`.

In my opinion, it makes little sense to use policies you don't understand well. Sometimes, there might be very good reasons to break some of them;  blindly following Perl Critic (especially at more stern levels) doesn't bring you anything.

Comment: please check the edited question, when i loop around that array and look for string $n in the item of an array, perl critic gives one more error.

Comment: Perl critic gives no errors. It just tells you `$n` looks like a variable, but won't be interpolated in single quotes. If your process needs to silent severity 1 warnings, add a `## no critic (ValuesAndExpressions::RequireInterpolationOfMetachars)` comment plus explanation why `$n` shouldn't be interpolated here.

Comment: Also, next time, use a new question to ask a new question. You may link to the previous one if you think their relevance is important.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is IMO a false positive, since `while` is acting as the conditional here - the `push @array, $1` won't get executed unless the regexp matched, which is what the policy wants (add `--verbose 11` to the `perlcritic` invocation to see the explanations). This is a case where I think it's safe to suppress the policy, as I show below.

The second one is easy to fix, simply replace `$n =~ /.../xg` with `$n =~ m{...}xg`.

```perl
push @array, $1  ## no critic (ProhibitCaptureWithoutTest)
    while $n =~ m{ ... }xg;
```

That suppresses those two messages.

As a side note, running `perlcritic` at `brutal` severity is IMO a little extreme, and it'll complain about a lot of other stuff in that snippet. Personally, when I use it, I run `perlcritic` at `harsh` (`-3`) with a few policies at customized levels.

*Edit:* As for your third `perlcritic` message, which you added to your post later, it looks like that's been answered in [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50092032/9300627).