# Perl critic policy violation in checking index of substring in a string

Tags: string, perl, substring, perl-critic

```
for my $item (@array) {
    if (index($item, '$n') != -1) {
       print "HELLO\n";
    }
}
```

Problem is: Perl critic gives below policy violation.

> String may require interpolation at line 168, near '$item, '$n''. (Severity: 1)

Please advise how do I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091407/perl-critic-error-on-splitting-string-into-array-using-regexp#comment87200376_50091571

Answer (score 3):

In this case the analyzer either found a bug or is plain wrong in flagging your code.

Are you looking for a literal "*$n*" in `$item`, or for what `$n` variable evaluates to?

- If you want to find the literal *$n* characters then there is nothing wrong with your code
- If you expect `$item` to contain the value stored in `$n` variable then allow it to be evaluated,

  ```
  if (index($item, $n)  != -1)
  ```

  If this is indeed the case but `$n` may also contain yet other escaped sequences or encodings which you need as literal characters (so to suppress their evaluation) then you may need to do a bit more, depending of what exactly may be in that variable.

In case you do need to find characters `$` followed by `n` (what would explain a deliberate act of putting single quotes around a variable) you need to handle the warning.

For the particular policy that is violated see [Perl::Critic::Policy::ValuesAndExpressions](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/ValuesAndExpressions/RequireInterpolationOfMetachars.pm)

> This policy warns you if you use single-quotes or q// with a string that has unescaped metacharacters that may need interpolation.

To satisfy the policy you'd need to use double quotes and escape the `$`, for example `qq(\$n)`. In my opinion this would change the fine original code segment into something strange to look at.

If you end up wanting to simply silence the warning see documentation, in [Bending The Rules](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/Perl-Critic-1.130/lib/Perl/Critic.pm#BENDING_THE_RULES)

A comment. The *tool* [perlcritic](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/Perl-Critic-1.130/lib/Perl/Critic.pm) is useful but you have to use it right. It's a static code analyzer and it doesn't know what your program is doing, so to say; it can catch bad practices but can't tell you how to write programs.  Many of its "policies" are unsuitable for particular code.

The [book that it is based on](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001735.do) says all this very nicely in its introduction.    Use sensibly.

---

When I look at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50091407/4653379) where this comes from it appears that you are looking for index at which substrings were matched, so you need the content of `$n` variable, not literal "*$n*". Then `perlcritic` identified a bug in the code, good return for using it!